# How to set edittext values after intent back to old activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am working with Android. I have a button and EditText in Activity A. When I click on the button it goes to Activity B with an Intent. I have a ListView in Acivity B. I clicked on list item and stored the values in string and again go back to Activity A with an Intent. Now I want to set the values in the EditText field in activity A. Is it possible????

Comment: use OnActivityResult() to pass result from activity B to activity A.

Comment: When you go to Activity B to Activity A set String into Bundle

Comment: yes you can do this onresume() method in activity A. pass the values to activity A from activity B.Set the values for edittext in onresume method in activity A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass data between activities in Intents. Here's how you might structure the code in your case:

1. Create a static variable in your ActivityA class, which will be used as request code:

   ```
   public class ActivityA extends Activity {

       //declare a static variable here, in your class
       public static final int ACTIVITYB_REQUEST = 100;
   ```
2. Activity A: when button is clicked, create an Intent and startActivityForResult()

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_REQUEST);
   ```
3. In Activity B: when clicked an item, store your string in an intent and call setResult() and finish(), which will take you back to Activity A:

   ```
   //create an Intent
   Intent resultIntent = new Intent();

   //add your string from the clicked item
   resultIntent.putExtra("string_key", clicked_item_string);

   //return data back to parent, which is Activity A
   setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);

   //finish current activity
   finish();
   ```
4. In Activity A: override onActivityResult(), check for returned data and set your EditText accordingly

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       //check if we are back from Activity B...
       if (requestCode == ACTIVITYB_REQUEST) {
           //and all went fine...
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               //if Intent is not null
               if (data != null) {

                   //get your string 
                   String newString = data.getExtras().getString("string_key");

                   //set your EditText
                   someEditText.setText(newString);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: public static final ACTIVITYB_REQUEST = 100; shows error "final invalid type"

Comment: Should be public static final int ACTIVITYB_REQUEST = 100; I forgot to add variable type, which is `int`...

Comment: You need to declare ACTIVITYB_REQUEST as a member variable in your class, NOT inside any method. See updated answer.

Comment: I am used onfocus action for edittext instead of button action, for passing intent. is it possible??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46342/discussion-between-melquiades-and-doubter)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You need to simple put the values in the bundle and send that bundle to Activity A through intent.

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(ActivitA.this, ActivtyB.class);
intent.putExtra(name, value);
startActiivty(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to acommplish has 2 parts: Passing the intent value itself to the other
activity (most answers already explained it)
And second, how to modify the EditText or TextView itself, because if you try
to do it inside an OnActivityResultMethod, it wont work directly, and will have to do this workaround:

You can force a EditText.SetText("blablabla..."); inside your OnActivity Result 
in 3 EASY steps:

1. Reload your layout into your Activity
2. Rebind your EditText
3. use SetText as usual.

In this sample code, I pass a URL string with and intent and write it into a TextView:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{       
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    {
        QRdata= data.getStringExtra("QRURL");

        if (QRdata.length()>0)
        {
                            //Step1
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirmpackage); 
                            //Step2
            TextView qrtxt=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.qrurl); 
                            //Setp 3,Voilà!
            qrtxt.setText(QRdata.toString()); 
        }
```